# llenar array con map y axios

Tags: javascript, array, axios

Estoy intentando crear un arreglo con map, y por cada iteración necesito traer información con get axios, pero la variable de nuevo arreglo al finalizar el map me trae los elementos como undefined.

```
let nuevo_arreglo = main_res.results.map( item => {
  axios.get(url).then(res => {
  return res
 })
});
```

Hay alguna forma de hacer que guarde el arreglo correctamente, soy nuevo en javascript.

Comment: Tu problema está en el manejo de la asincronía. Las peticiones de `axios` no se resolverán de forma síncrona, por lo cual al momento en que intentas usar tu variable, la misma no contiene la data que crees que debe contener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Tal como digo en mi [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/494215/llenar-array-con-map-y-axios#comment878297_494215), tu problema (y siempre lo es) es de asincronía.

Si hacemos un ejercicio mental de lo que está sucediendo con tu código, tienes una lista (array) de ítems, y por cada uno de ellos realizas una petición tipo `get` usando [`axios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), que es una librería `http` basada en [Promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises). Esto significa que el resultado de dicha petición estará disponible en un momento futuro incierto, haciendo que la asignación del resultado del método `map` a tu variable `nuevo_arreglo` no tenga realmente los datos devueltos de dicha o dichas Promesas. Incluso si las mismas retornaran inmediatamente, el contenido de ellas sería un Objeto de tipo Promesa y no el resultado procesado de la misma.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una posible solución es usar el método [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) para procesar el nuevo arreglo una vez que todas las Promesas del arreglo original hayan sido procesadas. Sin embargo, dado que `Promise.all` devuelve a su vez una Promesa, la forma correcta de seguir trabajando con el resultado de la misma es dentro del método `then()` de dicha Promesa.

```js
// INCORRECTO
let nuevo_arreglo = main_res.results.map( item => {
  axios.get(url).then(res => {  // <= axios.get devuelve una Promesa
    return res;  // <= este return no devuelve nada a map, sino a la Promesa
  });
});

// CORRECTO
// Promise.all recibe como argumento un iterable cuyos elementos son Promesas
Promise.all(main_res.results.map( item => { return axios.get(url) }))
.then(nuevo_arreglo => {  // el resultado será un arreglo nuevo con los resultados de cada Promesa (siempre que todas hayan sido resueltas)
  nuevo_arreglo.forEach(result => {
    console.log(result.data);  // el resultado está en la propiedad data del objeto devuelto
  });
});
```

Podemos ver un ejemplo en funcionamiento, usando la API de [randomuser.me](https://randomuser.me/), para procesar una lista de peticiones:

```js
let items = [
  'https://randomuser.me/api/?inc=gender,name,nat&nat=US&results=1',
  'https://randomuser.me/api/?inc=gender,name,nat&nat=ES&results=1',
  'https://randomuser.me/api/?inc=gender,name,nat&nat=FR&results=1'
];

Promise.all(items.map(axios.get))
.then(nuevo_arreglo => {
  nuevo_arreglo.forEach(result => {
    console.log(result.data);
  });
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Otra forma de resolver el problema es usando [`async / await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) y un bucle [`for ... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). Pero para que esto funcione, tu código debe ser ejecutado en un entorno tipo `async` (nótese que he envuelto la función anónima entre paréntesis y al final he puesto doble paréntesis para indicar su ejecución: `(func_anonima)()`), por ejemplo:

```js
let items = [
  'https://randomuser.me/api/?inc=gender,name,nat&nat=US&results=1',
  'https://randomuser.me/api/?inc=gender,name,nat&nat=ES&results=1',
  'https://randomuser.me/api/?inc=gender,name,nat&nat=FR&results=1'
];

// entorno async / await autoejecutado

(async () => {
  let nuevo_arreglo = [];
  // siempre que usamos async / await debemos usar try / catch para el manejo de Promesas
  try {
    for ( let item of items ) {
      let result = await axios.get(item);
      nuevo_arreglo.push(result.data);
    }
    console.log(nuevo_arreglo);
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
})();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.